# Unable to get information from a specified session at Paypal IPN page

Tags: perl, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

The page is set with notify url for paypal payment. I want to get the information from a predefined session. I am not getting any output from the predefined session in this ipn page while there are no issues with other pages.

sample codes:

```
use CGI::Session;
my $session = CGI::Session->new or die CGI::Session->errstr;
my $info_var = $session->param("info_var");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a session on the IPN URL? PayPal will post to this directly, bypassing the user, so you should be able to do what you need to do without maintaining state between requests.

Comment: Without creating a pre-order, I just wanted to handle the the data from session. But finally did it and used the ipn page for order verification only.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the session has expired. You should try using `load` instead of `new` because `new` will create new session if it doesn't find any.

```
$session = CGI::Session->load() or die CGI::Session->errstr();
if ( !$session->is_expired && !$session->is_empty ) {
    print $session->param("info_var"); 
}
```

Comment: Friend! I just checked the same, but still found the session param is nil.

Comment: I can see the session value in the ipn page if I just run it through url before paypal process. But it should be tracked after paypal process. No idea why it destroyed once the payment made at paypal site.